# Typescript refactoring (class renaming) issue in Webstorm 9

Tags: refactoring, typescript, webstorm

Any workaround for the following Typescript imported class name refactoring issue? The preview window does show the *correct* references to be refactored, however, when refactoring takes place, only the import statement is refactored.

1) File: animal.ts

```
class Animal {
    // ...
}
export = Animal;
```

2) File: main.ts

```
import X = require("animal");
var dog = new X(); // refactoring origin: trying to refactor X to Y
```

The error happens when I try to refactor (Shift+F6) Animal in main.ts: the preview window does show both references ("import X..." and "... new X"), but refactoring only renames the import statement.

Version tested: Webstorm 9.0.2 on Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Please vote for [WEB-14009](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14009)